# NEC uPD720200 USB 3.0 not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on a HP Envy 15 1104tx. Most stuff appears to be working fine with the exception of the two USB3 ports (USB2 port works fine). I've read a lot of articles but so far have not been able to find a solution.

I've tried adding 'pci=nomsi' to '/etc/default/grub' but this made no difference. Some articles suggest booting into Windows and upgrading the firmware on the uPD720200. Any body had any experience of this? Is there a way I can checked the firmware version of the NEC uPD720200 in Linux to see if there is an update available? Any help appreciated.

**uname -a:**

```
Linux HP-ENVY-15-1104tx 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lshw:**

```
    hp-envy-15-1104tx
    description: Notebook
    product: HP ENVY 15 Notebook PC (WF591PA#ABG)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: 0492110000241910001420000
    serial: CNF0301C79
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV sku=WF591PA#ABG uuid=434E4630-3330-3143-3739-60EB6906688F
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 1522
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: 36.35
       serial: CNF0301C79
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: 0
          version: F.2B
          date: 10/12/2010
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1472KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 13
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905428-043.A00LF
             physical id: 0
             serial: E13C4316
             slot: Bottom
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905428-043.A00LF
             physical id: 1
             serial: E03C3E16
             slot: Bottom
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905428-043.A00LF
             physical id: 2
             serial: 672279CC
             slot: On Board
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905428-043.A00LF
             physical id: 3
             serial: 652286CC
             slot: On Board
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 820  @ 1.73GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1d
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 820  @ 1.73GHz
          slot: CPU
          size: 1199MHz
          capacity: 1199MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1066MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 1e
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 20
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 21
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-through instruction
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 1f
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DMI
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 11
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:d4100000-d41fffff ioport:c0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Broadway PRO [Mobility Radeon HD 5800 Series]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:58 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d4100000-d411ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d4140000-d415ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:56 memory:d4120000-d4123fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:d4000000-d40fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: NEC Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:d4000000-d4001fff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor System Management Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor System Control and Status Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.2
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.3
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:4 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor QPI Link
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:5 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 10.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.1
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:55 memory:d4200000-d4203fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d3000000-d3ffffff ioport:d0000000(size=16777216)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 35
                serial: 00:27:10:40:e4:68
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-26-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:54 memory:d3000000-d3001fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d2000000-d2ffffff ioport:d1000000(size=16777216)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
                vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: c0
                serial: 60:eb:69:06:68:8f
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=10.161.0.147 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:57 memory:d2000000-d203ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:d4205800-d4205bff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:45 ioport:5048(size=8) ioport:5054(size=4) ioport:5040(size=8) ioport:5050(size=4) ioport:5020(size=32) memory:d4205000-d42057ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: OCZ-VERTEX3
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 2.15
                serial: OCZ-0350P6H316X5KUQE
                size: 223GiB (240GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000592dd
              *-volume:0
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: e741f18c-cfc5-4bce-b1e7-f80e517a3a22
                   size: 207GiB
                   capacity: 207GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2012-06-15 06:49:27 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-06-14 21:23:42 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-07-10 16:18:20 state=mounted
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 15GiB
                   capacity: 15GiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 15GiB
                      capabilities: nofs
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d4205c00-d4205cff ioport:5000(size=32)
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Physical 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.1
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.4
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.1
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.2
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:11
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10b
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.3
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:12
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10c
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:13
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10d
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.1
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:14
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10e
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.2
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:15
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 10f
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.3
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       product: NK06053
       vendor: SMP-ATL24
       physical id: 1
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 4800mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
```

**lspci:**

```
02:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1522
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

**lsusb** (with thumb drive plugged into USB3 port):

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:01d0 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue by flashing the firmware on the NEC uPD720200. Posting the answer here in case anybody else experiences this issue.

Downloads a windows boot CD from here (Boot_CD.iso):

http://www.gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?t=7171

Downloaded the latest NEC firmware (version 4.0.2.0) from here:

http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=select&id=196&lang=en

- Burn iso file to CD.
- Copy firmware .exe file to a USB key.
- Reboot computer/laptop with Boot CD in drive.
- Once booted you should be presented with a DOS prompt.
- Insert USB key containing firmware .exe.
- Navigate to C: and run firmware executable to extract the firmware files.
- Change to 'firmware' sub directory, and run 'uPD720200_uPD720200A_FW_Updater.exe'
- Reboot laptop/computer and check is USB3.0 ports work under Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately the driver download link is dead. I have not been able to find drivers anywhere, any hints appreciated!

Comment: @kynan Link fixed.

Comment: I don't think I'd trust that firmware unless it came from the manufacturer or I had a hashsum, or something.  What is "station-drivers.com"??

Answer (score 1):

Because the other answers might have some in-accuracies, here is the pairing between devices, revisions and firmware revisions:

uPD720200a -> rev.4 -> firmware 4.x.x.x and maybe 3.x.x.x

uPD720200 -> rev.3 -> firmware 3.x.x.x only

The question might have been about revision 3 but some answers seem to talk about revision 4. Please take care for not beeing misled.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although we appreciate that you are trying to help, this is not a complete answer, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/827393/edit) your answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after updating the firmware to version `4.0.2.0` for a `uPD720200a` controller card and applying power to the `4-pin Molex` connector on the card.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed very quirky USB 3 port in Lenovo T420s in linux.

I installed the manufacturer firmware update in Windows 10 instead of following Jagged's procedure.

Note: Unlike as stated in Alexander Stohr post, I was able to update the newest 4.0.2.0 / rev.4 firmware to uPD720200(non-a). I think the firmware manufacturer just forgot to add both models to all file names in that uPD720200/720200a folder hence the confusion.