# External PCIe USB 3.0 Controller NEC Corporation uPD720200 not recocnized since the upgrade to 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, usb

I use an external USB 3.0 PCIe card. It used to work like a charm on 13.10. But ever since the upgrade to 14.04 hot-plug doesn't seem to work any more. It used to work before.

Only when this card is plugged in a boot it's working. 
dmesg shows:
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)

When plugged in during operation I only get some message that a hot-plug event took place. Other than that nothing happens.

Any idea why?

---

### Edit 2014-06-14:

I have been searching up and down the /var/log folder.

Seems to me, the kernel doesn't recognize the card at all during hot-plug

#### boot with PCIe external Card installed

lspci command:

```
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

/var/log/dmesg:

```
[    1.314043] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.314049] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.314343] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.314350] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.314356] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.314362] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.314369] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.314544] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.314546] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.314548] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.314549] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-30-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.314551] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:03:00.0
[    1.314658] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.314672] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    1.314742] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.314746] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.317621] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.317622] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.317624] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.317625] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-30-generic xhci_hcd
[    1.317627] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:03:00.0
[    1.317700] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.317713] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
```

/var/log/sys.log: (Kernal message when plugging in an external USB 3.o harddisk)

```
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.002797] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.020710] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.023650] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a00d
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.023661] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.023667] usb 4-1: Product: External USB 3.0
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.023672] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.023677] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 23183A26B28E
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/usb4/4-1"
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.047210] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.047466] scsi6 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
Jun 14 15:19:09 marina711 kernel: [  403.047575] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.305836] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 5438 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.306478] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.307703] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525164 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.308102] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.308106] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.308805] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.317164]  sdc: sdc1
Jun 14 15:19:13 marina711 kernel: [  406.344720] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

/var/log/udev:

```
UDEV  [4.174356] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0 (pci)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0
DRIVER=xhci_hcd
ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=NEC Corporation
MODALIAS=pci:v00001033d00000194sv0000FFFFsd0000FFFFbc0Csc03i30
PCI_CLASS=C0330
PCI_ID=1033:0194
PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:03:00.0
PCI_SUBSYS_ID=FFFF:FFFF
SEQNUM=1666
SUBSYSTEM=pci
USEC_INITIALIZED=85
```

#### Messages with card hot-plugged:

lspci: nothing found

/var/log/dmesg: nothing found

dmesg command:

```
[   31.456256] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0: Bus check notify on hotplug_event_root
```

/var/log/kern.log: nothing found

/var/log/sys.log: nothing found

/var/log/udev: nothing found

dmesg command after unplug:

```
[  719.603717] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0: Bus check notify on hotplug_event_root
```

Compared the loaded modules on lsmod for both cases: No difference found

When the card was plugged at boot time it appears on lspci. When I unplug it then, it is still there!

Comment: This seems to be related:  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/161862/nec-upd720200-usb-3-0-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: No that didn't help. My Chipset is uPD720200 not uPD720200A. I upgraded the firmware to the most recent (3.0.34) but the situation is still the same.

Comment: On re-reading; it apperars as some driver gets loaded (a kernel module?) as you boot with the hardware present. Try this: Boot with the card plugged in, then grep on the parts of "03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)" and see if you can find out what there is happening related to it. That might give ideas on how to get the thing running at hot-plug-in.