# How can I debug my Tiergrade TG-HB017 USB 3.0 PCI-E Card?

Tags: drivers, usb, pcie

I have installed [the component](https://www.tiergrades.com/products/tiergrade-7-ports-pci-e-to-usb-3-0-expasion-card), and it does pass power to things plugged into it (mouse laser turns on).  But it does not respond to any input.

If you read the reviews on Amazon, it's a mixed bag of ["works in Linux perfect" to "doesn't work at all"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z34BJYH)

I found this piece of advice on the Amazon questions:

> (AMD x64) Linux 4.4.0-203-generic works fine after I added this line to
> /etc/default/grub
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
> then
> update-grub
> on Intel, you might need this line instead of above grub line
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=off"
> 10x improvement over USB2, which is great!

Unfortunately this did not do the trick.

What I'd like to know is how to approach solving this problem (not just the final answer).

How can I tell that the device is recognized, or find error messages related to it?

How can I get a better idea of what it's doing, if anything?

How would I go about figuring out why it doesn't work, if not for someone on the internet telling me the answer?

Comment: here's a place to start :  https://appuals.com/how-to-check-pci-slots-in-linux/  I would also check syslogs and see what's there as well.  `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i error` .  There is also `journalctl`  You can also view syslogs `sudo less /var/log/syslog`

Comment: great start.  I tried running `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` to see what happens when I un/plug on the port, and no logs are created at all.  Upon running `lspci` there was one item which might be the usb card (the only USB related thing not made by the motherboard company).  It has the id `06:00.0`.  Do you know how I could read more into this device to tell if it's the right one, or anything it might be doing?

Comment: I found this in the forum : https://askubuntu.com/questions/601706/usb-3-0-usb-pci-card-not-working?rq=1  see if anything there helps you