# RENESAS uPD720201/uPD720202 USB3.0 PCI-E Card Not Detected

Tags: usb

I have the same issue as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461884/renesas-usb3-0-pci-e-card-not-detected), lspci doesn't show it. dmidecode says the PCIE x1 slot (the only PCIE x1 slot on my mother board) is available (i.e. doesn't say its in use). The card is uPD720201/uPD720202 based and works fine on a windows system (different PC). The firmware was updated to [version 2024](http://ftp2.station-drivers.com/index.php/downloads/Drivers/Renesas-Nec/USB-3.0/Renesas-Nec-uPD720201-720202-USB-3.0-Controller-Firmware-Version-2.0.2.4/). It is powered with molex connector. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

No where in the syslog or dmesg or kern.log there is any xhci seen with grep. Even NEC/Renesas nothing shows in these logs. Its as if my card was silently missing.

Bit more information:

```
$uname -a
Linux ******* 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Packard Bell BV
        Product Name: Cuba MS-7301
        Version: 1.0
        Serial Number:
```

```
Handle 0x0025, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: PCIEX16
        Type: x16 PCI Express
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Long
        ID: 4
        Characteristics:
                5.0 V is provided
                PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: PCIEX1_1
        Type: x1 PCI Express
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        ID: 5
        Characteristics:
                5.0 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
```

Even `lspci -nn` also doesn't show the card as opposed to what was stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583626/trouble-with-usb3-chipset-upd720201)

I noticed that when I connect the same card to my other desktop (running windows and dual-booting to ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) the dmi decode shows that my card is powered 3.3V. This is weird, I thought PCIEX_x16 & PCIEX_x1 are all common standard and common voltage. Any idea why the voltage is different, anyone please?

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
    Product Name: M4A79XTD EVO
    Version: Rev X.0X
    Serial Number: MT709CK11102337
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCIEX16_1
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCIEX16_2
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCIEX1_1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCIEX1_2
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Short
    ID: 5
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Short
    ID: 13
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI2
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 14
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
```

In this case lspci -nn does show the card and the card works.

```
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1912:0015] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Same problem on me :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this answer provides the essential: https://askubuntu.com/a/794911/68124

> That kernel is way too old. Initial usb 3 support was added to 2.6, but the real support for xhci was added in 4.4-4.6. It's part of the linux-firmware load as well as the kernel proper.